# Populating the Condition of IF statement from a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I want to populate the condition of IF statement from a table in the database stored in SQL Server.
For retrieving the Condition from SQL Server I am using:

```
...
SQL_Cond = "SELECT Cond FROM Condition"
Recordset.open SQL_Cond,ConnString
Cond = Recordset(0).value
MsgBox Cond
...
```

This shows the Condition in MsgBox, Condition is something like '0.8*Table_A_Rows > Table_B_Rows' stored as a varchar in sqlserver. Now I want to use this condition in the if statement as follows

```
...
if (Cond) Then
    ...
    'Process
    ...
 End If
```

So basically Can the Condition string be typecasted into a datatype which does not show a Type Mismatch and when placed inside the parameter of IF? Is this even Feasible ?

The following works Perfectly in VbScript:

```
...
Dim Cond = A>B  'Which datatype is this?? Lets call it CONDITION Data Type
If (Cond) Then
    MsgBox "A>B"
Else
    MsgBox "A<B"
```

But can a string be converted to this CONDITION Data type for usage in IF Statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eval()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After your query `cond` is a string, hopefully containing a valid boolean expression. You can use [`Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to evalute the expression in your If statement:

```
>> A = 1
>> B = 0
>> cond = "A>B"
>> If Eval(cond) Then WScript.Echo "Yes"
>>
Yes
```

This works, because A and B are known in the evaluation's context. You have to make sure that this holds for your variables like Table_A_Rows.